# Bounding $1/\zeta(s)$ given RH

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Let $T\geq 0$. Assume RH(T+100), that is, assume that all non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function with $|\Im(\rho)|\leq T+100$ satisfy $\Re(\rho)=1/2$. Can we then give a good upper bound on $|1/\zeta(s)|$ (that is, a good lower bound on $|\zeta(s)|$) for $s=\sigma+it$, $|t|\leq T$, $\sigma=3/4$ or $\sigma=1$, say?

(There are well-known analogous bounds on $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$.)

Comment: Why call it GRH? Isn't this just (restricted) RH?

Comment: Theorem 14.8 of Titchmarsh gives a bound for $\log\zeta(1+it)$, and 14.5 gives a bound further to the left. I guess you can truncate the integral (cf. top page 342, top page 343) in the approximate functional equation method when you only have a finite RH assumption.

Comment: I think you are going to need to assume RH up to $T+(\log T)^c$ to get a bound on $1/\zeta(s)$ up to $T$. Not sure what $c$ is optimally, but likely 2 by Titchmarsh's presentation.

Comment: Actually, why can't you just integrate the well-known $\zeta'/\zeta$ bounds to get $\log\zeta$? Also, I think that the Caratheodory/Hadamard methodology (14.2) will reduce the needed zero-free region to $T+100$ as you indicated. Maybe one could do the same with the approximate functional equation if you really wanted to.

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but wouldn't a brutal attempt in that direction result in multiplying the bounds on $\zeta'/\zeta$ by the length of the path of integration?

Comment: Oh I see, you are going to integrate from $2+it$ to $\sigma+it$, right? Well, then you still need to exponentiate.

Comment: I don't think you are doing better than $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\gg\exp(-C(\log t)^{2(1-\sigma)}/\log\log t)$ in any event. Even under RH, as indicated by Titchmarsh (with $\nu(\sigma)$ in 14.3), the best hope would likely be to replace 2 by 1.

Comment: What about $\sigma=1$? It is not immediately obvious to me that you recover $1/\zeta(1+it) = \log \log$ in this way. At any rate, yes, for $\sigma<1$, Titchmarsh simply integrates $\zeta'/\zeta$.

Comment: Again the details need to be worked out, but I think from the approximate functional equation you get $|\log \zeta(1+it)|\le (1+\alpha)\log\log\log t+C$ where $\alpha$ is something like $\exp(-100\pi/2)$ (for your choice of 100).